# SSH key pair - add to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

When you create a Key Pair in the AWS console, then create an EC2 instance is that key automatically added to that instance?

Or do you have to add it when creating the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 3):

While launching an EC2 instance from **AWS Console**, you will be prompted to choose a Key Pair. The Public Key of this chosen Key Pair will be added to the `authorized_keys` file of the default login user.

If launching an EC2 instance using
**AWS CLI:**

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-id --key-name name_of_keypair --other-options
```

**Python Boto3:**

```
ec2client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-id',
                        KeyName='name_of_keypair',
                        ....)
```

Comment: I'm wanting to launch the instance using the CLI (using Boto3).